# Unable to access node server running on specific port from other machine

Tags: node.js, networking, port

I am running  node server running react application.server is run by webpack. Server is running on 10.121.45.23:3005. I tried opening the application on other machine but page displays connection timed out. I have tried following things to resolve the issue, but nothing helped.

1. `ping 10.121.45.23` from another machine. It is successful.
2. On server, `netstat -ano`. I am able to see 10.121.45.23:3005 listening. No loopback address was there as mentioned in many answers on Stack Overflow.
3. On another machine,telnet 10.121.45.23 3005. It fails and say cannot connect on port 3005. Telnet to some other port on which java is running, is successful. It fails only for node.js server.

So my problems are:

- telnet is not working to that port.
- Not able to open application on other machine's browser.

Am I missing any checks?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've tested quiet a bit.  Have you tried another port, just in case there's a firewall or something?
Also, try explicitly telling webpack to listen on the all-hosts address `0.0.0.0`

```
webpack-dev-server --port 9000 --host 0.0.0.0
```